# How can I ignore the initial override of a default attribute on a Polymer element within the changed event handler for that attribute?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, custom-element

It seems like the changed event handler for any given attribute fires even when initializing the element the first time with a value other than the default value for that attribute.

For example, let's say I have the following custom Polymer element.

```
<polymer-element name="some-thing" attributes="name">
    <script>
        Polymer({
            name: 'John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt',
            nameChanged: function (oldValue, newValue) {
                console.log('name changed from ' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer>
```

When I include this element in my markup, the name changed event handler fires right away even though I'm not conceptually "changing" the value but rather initializing it.

```
<some-thing name="Peter Peter Pumpkin Eater"></some-thing>
```

I only want the event handler to fire when external code modifies the value of the element's name attribute. Is there a way that I can set up an event handler to behave in this way?

Answer (score 0):

when the value of name is changed you can check if it has value with a if statment.

```
nameChanged: function () {
  if (this.name) {
    // only ran when there is a value
  }
}
```

or for that matter you might could check newValue. i have never tried this.

```
 if (newValue) {
   // only ran when there is a value
 }
```

there might be a cleaner method but this has worked for me.

edit: also using a created function to set the value of name might keep it from firing 2 times. try something like.

```
  created: function () {
    this.name = this.name || "Peter Cottontail";
  }
```

edit again: changed ready function to a created function. i think ready function would still cause the value to change 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

You should check a type of the oldValue to ignore first assignment:

```
Polymer({
  /* ... */
  nameChanged: function (oldValue, newValue) {
    if ('undefined' !== typeof oldValue) {
       // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please *avoid overriding existing attribute names*, like `name`, `title` etc. This brings a lot of problems in many ways in different browsers. I will use `someName` for the attribute name below.

Generally speaking whether you have an attribute specified explicitely in your light DOM with:

```
<some-thing someName="Peter Peter Pumpkin Eater"></some-thing>
```

the event is to be fired, since the name was changed. You are permitted to have some logic relying on the fact that name is a default one:

```
if (this.someName === 'John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt') {
  // we are on initials, let’s do nothing here
}
```

That’s why an event *is to be fired*. Whether you still want to suppress firing these events for values, specified in light DOM, you might use the following workaroung:

```
<polymer-element name="some-thing" attributes="someName">
  <script>
    Polymer({
      someName: 'John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt',
      isDomReady: false, // will use this to prevent onSomeNameChanged
      someNameChanged: function (oldValue, newValue) {
        if(!this.isDomReady) return; // skip, we are not yet initialized
        console.log('name changed from ' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue);
      },
      domReady: function() {
        this.isDomReady = true;
        this.async(function() { this.someName = 'Humpty Dumpty' });
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
//⇒ name changed from Peter Peter Pumpkin Eater to Humpty Dumpty
```

Live preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/uArV1FbZW7ONRzv5DN8f?p=preview